# Js to html conversion using Webkit gives empty <html>, <head>, <body> tags

Tags: python, html, webkit, web-scraping

I am using the code from this site
http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/

to try to scrape this page 
http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v36/li14.pdf

which is rendered by js. So basically I convert it to html and plan to use BeautifulSoup on the html

But my code :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Render(QWebPage):
   def __init__(self, url):
      self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      QWebPage.__init__(self)
      self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
      self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
      self.app.exec_()

   def _loadFinished(self, result):
      self.frame = self.mainFrame()
      self.app.quit()

url = 'http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v36/li14.pdf'
r = Render(url)
html = r.frame.toHtml() #gives only head, body, html as empty
print unicode(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(html))
print(soup)
```

And this is my output:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I really need to scrape this page and WITHOUT downloading it and using pdfminer/pypdf. This is the simplest method I found and works for the example site in the site that gave this code

I understand it probably has somethng to do with multiple js scripts running on my site and I probably need to specify which js script in the function, but I don't know js and this is my first time with python. Any ideas?

Comment: The JS tag isn't relevant here. Removed.

Comment: @Cerbrus: What about "which is rendered by js"?

Comment: @RichieHindle: There isn't a JS solution to this issue. This question doen't require the answerer to know JS, just to realize the OP isn't looking to scrape plain HTML

Comment: Not sure what your intent is, but your url is a pdf file which is rendered by pdf plugin. Firefox uses pdfjs (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) which might be useful in this scenario.